# Data is Not Getting post on the web service

Tags: ios

I want to post Dictionary to a Web service. but it is not getting post .Every time when i post data i am getting error message form web-service. I also try different approach using `AFNetworking` but using that approach i am getting 406 error.

you can see the other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294283/getting-request-failed-unacceptable-406-when-posting-parameters)

```
 NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[params setValue:self.txtUserName.text forKey:@"name"];
[params setValue:self.txtEmail.text forKey:@"mail"];
[params setValue:self.txtPass.text forKey:@"conf_mail"];
[params setValue:self.txtPass2.text forKey:@"pass"];

NSData *body=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:params];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://web.info/ministore/store-commerce/user/register"]];
  [request setHTTPBody:body];


[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request
                                   queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError)
{
    if (connectionError){
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", connectionError);
          [ProgressHUD dismiss];
    }
    else {
         NSLog(@"data as String: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
         NSError *e = nil;
         NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&e];

         NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];
        NSMutableDictionary *dict1=[dict objectForKey:@"data"];
         NSLog(@"data -- %@",[dict objectForKey:@"data"]);
        NSLog(@"status -- %@",[dict objectForKey:@"status"]);
        int num=[[dict valueForKey:@"status"]intValue];
        if( num== 0)
        {
            NSString *strMail=[dict1 valueForKey:@"mail"];
            NSString *strName=[dict1 valueForKey:@"name"];
            NSString *strPass=[dict1 valueForKey:@"pass"];

            if(strMail.length==0)
            {
                strMail=@"";
            }
            if(strName.length==0)
            {
                strName=@"";
            }
            if(strPass.length==0)
            {
                strPass=@"";
            }
            NSString *Message=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Please correct the follwing \n %@ \n %@\n %@ ",strMail,strName,strPass];
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:Message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dict1 objectForKey:@"message"]] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
        }

           if (!jsonArray) {
                NSLog(@"Error parsing JSON: %@", e);
           }
        [ProgressHUD dismiss];
    }
}];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Request failed: unacceptable (406) when posting parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26294283/getting-request-failed-unacceptable-406-when-posting-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The body you posted generated by `NSData *body=[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:params];` is NSPropertyListBinaryFormat_v1_0 which is a binary serialize data.

Http server could not recognise it. You can POST by JSON

```
NSData *body = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:"NSDictionary variable name"
                                           options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                             error:&error];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://web.info/ministore/store-commerce/user/register"]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [body length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
```